# I want to use the text of a span which has attribute 'hidden'

Tags: jquery, html

I want to use the text inside of a span. this tag contains html5 `hidden` attribute.

```
<tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td>
        <button class="editBtn" title="Edit">Edit</button>
    </td>
    <span hidden>1</span>
</tr>
```

How can i fetch the text of the span using jquery ? I have tried but it gives me the wrong value. Every time it gives "2".

```
var value = $('.editBtn').closest('tr').children()[4].textContent;
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: invalid html......

Comment: @PranavCBalan Why it's invalid ?

Comment: child element of `tr` should be `td`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Ok, but when i did <input type="hidden" value="1" />  and try to fetch the value by var value = $('.editBtn').closest('tr').children()[4].value; Then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put span into td and then try:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td>
        <button class="editBtn" title="Edit">Edit</button>
    </td>
    <td>
    <span hidden>1</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
alert($('.editBtn').closest('tr').find('span').text());
```

Comment: I need to hidden the span tag

Answer (score 0):

```
var value= $('.editBtn').parentsUntil('tr').find('span').text();
```

Returns "1"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var value= $('.editBtn').parent('td').next('td').children('span').text();
console.log("Value is " + value);
```

Comment: i print the value of it in the console. It shows   [prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document]

Comment: var value= $('.editBtn').parent('td').next('td').children('span').text();
    console.log("Value is " + value);

Comment: it doesn't print the value of the var "value". May be it gets value = null